# Git: How to check what was fetched

Tags: git

Here I am on a branch working on some things.  I do a few `add`s, do a couple `commit`s.  Now, I do a `fetch` to get the remote changes into my remote tracking repository.

How can I get an understanding of what is what?

I know I can do `git diff origin/branch branch` to see what's different between my remote tracking and local branch.  But how can I tell what was fetched?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... the output of git fetch tells you exactly what it did.

Comment: Fetching doesn't merge the remote changes with your local branches, so the diff would only tell you what you don't have.

Comment: @bcmcfc It's possible I did this fetch last night when I was very tired, and upon waking today, I'm not sure what is happening.  It's possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Diff between local and remote

If you're only interested in the differences between local and remote after fetch, then you can use log commands between `.git/refs/heads/` and `.git/refs/remotes/origin/` or configured upstream branches like (note the dot usage compared to your command):

```
git log ..@{u}
git log branch..origin/branch
```

or for an advanced symmetric diff:

```
git log --oneline --left-right --cherry-pick ...@{u}
git log --oneline --left-right --cherry-pick branch...origin/branch
```

### What is fetched

That is logged by the command itself during execution:

```
$ git fetch 
(...)
From ...
   c1e6a44..8f13b81  master     -> origin/master
   b1304b4..359293c  branchA -> origin/branchA
 * [new branch]      branchB -> origin/branchB
```

Or with its verbose option (`-v`):

```
$ git fetch -v
(...)
From ...
   c1e6a44..8f13b81  master     -> origin/master
   b1304b4..359293c  branchA     -> origin/branchA
 = [up to date]      branchB     -> origin/branchB
 + 1e8827e...cf7aac7 branchC -> origin/branchC  (forced update)
```

As explained in [git help revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), `FETCH_HEAD` records the branch which you fetched from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation:

```
git log ..FETCH_HEAD
```

However, the previous content of `FETCH_HEAD` is lost. So you cannot later know exactly what was fetched only by the latest fetch command. Try the following command (you can make it a Git alias):

```
cp .git/FETCH_HEAD .git/FETCH_HEAD.old && git fetch -q && diff .git/FETCH_HEAD.old .git/FETCH_HEAD
```

### Incoming changes

I often use the following alias to check for incoming changes:

```
in = "!git remote update -p; git log ..@{u}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to see what has happened to origin/branch since you checked out your own branch:

I've made an alias for logging, called 'hist': [link](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_11.html)

In this project, I typed text into a file and created an initial commit.  I then cloned the repo and made a change in the clone.  I then went back to the origin and commited a change to the file.  Then I went into the copy and 'fetched'.  When I type 'git hist --all', this is the output:

```
* 69c8726 2014-09-25 | origin change (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
| * ee54c17 2014-09-25 | change from copy (HEAD, master)
|/
* 81ba217 2014-09-25 | initial commit
```

To see the differences between 'initial commit' and 'origin change', I type:

```
$ git diff 81ba217 origin/master

diff --git a/hello.txt b/hello.txt
index bfd905d..617496a 100644
--- a/hello.txt
+++ b/hello.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 this is text
+this is an origin change
```

Answer (score 1):

Using whatever git command you want to show information, you would use the following revision specification

```
@{u}@{1}..@{u}
```

So for instance to list the commits you could use

```
git log --oneline @{u}@{1}..@{u}
```

To list the files you could use

```
git diff --name-only  @{u}@{1}..@{u}
```

Or any other form or log/diff you like.

This will work for any tracking branch you are currently checked out to.